# How can I unmarshall JSONp returned from a request?

Tags: json, api, go, jsonp

I'm attempting to use the [USDA's Farmers Market Directory API](http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/svcdesc.html) to receive a data about where nearby farmer's markets are located, using a zip code. I store the unmarshalled body of the response in:

```
type marketResponse struct {
        MapsLink string `json:"GoogleLink"`
        Address  string `json:"Address"`
        Schedule string `json:"Schedule"`
        Products string `json:"Products"`
}
```

Using the code:

```
//TODO: location: "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/locSearch?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng
resp, err := http.Get("http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=" + zipcode)
if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could net search zipcode %s: %v", zipcode, err)
}
defer func() {
        if err := resp.Body.Close(); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
        }
}()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
}

newMarket := &marketResponse{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, newMarket); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
}

log.Println("response: " + newMarket.Address)
```

The problem is, the response body is in JSONp, and I'm unmarshalling in JSON. How can I unmarshal in JSONp, using an external package, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response body is JSON - as per the response's `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8` header.

The issue is that your `marketResponse` struct bears no relation to the JSON returned. Using [JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/), your struct should look like:

```
type MarketResponse struct {
    Results []Result `json:"results"`
}

type Result struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Marketname string `json:"marketname"`
}
```

It's not clear where your existing `marketResponse` struct fits here, as neither API endpoint returns data with that structure.

PS: You should handle (or return) your errors and not just log them; logging them still means that your function continues with unhandled error. Your code might then panic when it encounters a nil response body or JSON unmarshalling error.

Comment: I was referring to the ex below the JavaScript example:

`detailResultHandler(
{
   "marketdetails": {
     "GoogleLink":"http://maps.google.com/?q=38.881112%2C%20-77.112179%20(%22Ballston+FRESHFARM+Market%22)",
     "Address":"901 N Taylor St, Ballston, Virginia, 22203",
     "Schedule":"June - October Thursday 3:00 PM to 7:00 PM",
     "Products":"Baked goods; Cheese and/or dairy products; Eggs; Fresh fruit and vegetables; Fresh and/or dried herbs; Honey; Meat; Poultry"
   }
}
);`


Although, I understand your point and will refactor it using two structs, `marketDetails` and what's inside